# execute shell script from crontab

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

Trying to execute shell script from crontab, every 10 seconds but it is not working for me

`* * * * * sleep 10 /path/dataimport.sh`

script just has one command `rake db:dataimport`

Comment: cron only allows down to the level of minutes not seconds so maybe you need a background process that is constantly running rather than a cron job?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working". Is it not running the script? Or not running the script when you expect it to?

Comment: @Shadwell shellscript  itself not calling

Answer (score 1):

The highest resolution for cron is minutes, so you can make the script run every minute like this :

```
* * * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: Sorry - an asterisk was missing. Try taking a look at the manual: http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Comment: thanks, I puted like this `* * * * * root $APP_DIR/script/dataimport.sh` and `* * * * * $APP_DIR/script/dataimport.sh`

Comment: sorry I puted like that, but still it is not working

Comment: You need six asterisks ("*"). Not five.

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to do it in a simple way..you must use [**Whenever Gem**](https://github.com/javan/whenever),made only for this purpose so that you can use plain simple words instead of scripting language for working on Cron jobs.

`install` it,generate the `schedule.rb` file using the `generator` and write the recurring tasks easily.

```
every 10.seconds do
  command "/usr/bin/my_great_command"
end
```

you can also use:-

```
##to run the scripts in schedule.rb
 bundle exec whenever
 ##update schedule.rb and run this to update and view your crontabs
 whenever --update-crontab
```